# Retrieve a pod inside a repo nested folder

Tags: ios, cocoapods, subdirectory, podspec, podfile

We have a developing framework which sharing repo with other frameworks. Here our currently structure:

```
- Repo root:
  - Framework A
  - Framework B
  - OurFramework:
    - OurFramework:
      - OurFramework.podspec
      - Code and other stuffs
```

Now we have to apply our framework to another project which is included with CI/CD. We have tried Submodule and Development pod method but it's not allow with current CI/CD setup. We decide to try this [podspec in the root of a library repo](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html). Here is our syntax in `pod file`:

```
pod 'FrameworkName', :git => 'git@github.com:company/rootRepoName.git', :branch => 'OurFramework-framework'
```

But when i `pod install` it said that `Unable to find a specification for 'OurFramework'`. We also try `:path =>` or `:podspec =>` to point at our .podspec file directory but it didn't help.
My question here is: Is there anyway to retrieve our pod framework privately without create another separated repo for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have founded a solution for this. So i bring `OurFramework.podspec` to repo root, then edit it to correct the source path:

```html
s.source_files = "OurFramework/OurFramework/Sources/**/*.{swift,h}"
```

After that it will work like a charm!